# How to assert that exactly the expected elements are in a list?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, pytest

I want to unit-test a function that takes a list and returns (a very different) list. I know what elements I expect, but I do not know in what order they will me in the returned list. How can I assert that exactly those elements are in the list an no other? I would like to do this using py.test. Also: I expect to have multiple duplicates.

Comment: So, are you wanting to check order as well? Or just that it "contains" those elements?

Comment: @idjaw: Only containing, but I do have duplicates and they shall be checked for as well.

Comment: OK. So you are looking for ensuring two lists contain the same information but not necessarily the same order. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to test if list A and list B have the exact same elements, including duplicates but disregarding order.
This calls for use of Counters:

```
from collections import Counter
wanted_elements = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
input_list = [1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3]
c1 = Counter(wanted_elements)
c2 = Counter(input_list)
assert c1 == c2
```

Comment: I checked out https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects, but I am not quite sure why this works.

Comment: You're simply counting the occurrences of each element in list A, then counting the occurrences of each element in list B, and then testing to see that they are the same.  The == operator between Counters checks all of their keys for equality.

Comment: Do I need to implement `hash` and/or `eq` for that?

Comment: Counter is a subclass of dict, so hash yes, eq no.

Comment: Is this faster than `assert sorted(exampleOutput) == sorted(func(inputList))`?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the elements are hashable and unique, just use sets:

```
set(l) == set(f(l))
```

If those conditions don't apply, sort them:

```
sorted(l) == sorted(f(l))
```

And there's `collections.Counter`, if the elements are hashable and non-unique:

```
import collections

collections.Counter(l) == collections.Counter(f(l))
```

Comment: This doesn't handle duplicates, which may be important

Answer (score 1):

If order doesn't matter, sort both lists and check their equality

```
assert sorted(exampleOutput) == sorted(func(inputList))
```

Comment: If you are sorting both lists, you could use assertListEqual, from unittest library. There's probably something equivalent in pytest. Something like:

expected = sorted(example_output)
received = sorted(input_output)
self.assertEqual(expected, received)

Comment: @vribeiro: Haven't found anything like it in py.test :-(

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the set operation difference:

```
list_to_test = [1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1,2]
wanted_elements = [1,2,3]
d = set(list_to_test).difference(set(wanted_elements))
print d
set([4, 5])
```

and so eventually you would assert that len(d) == 0.

Comment: Good idea, but I don't see it dealing with duplicates.

Comment: In what way you want to deal with duplicates? This method will alert you if the list you get has any unwanted elements... If you allow element 'A' and get it twice in the list -- is that a problem?